# Do I have access to the private key for an Instawallet?

Tags: e-wallet, instawallet

It is just numbers and letters? I have transferred my bitcoin address and want to use the key so I can move my coins from this wallet to another? As you may be aware there site is down but can I set this up on another wallet so I can still get my coins?

Comment: You are misunderstanding something somewhere.  Instawallet never reveals the private key for the Bitcoin address tied to your Instawallet.

Comment: Isn't the No's/letters on the end of the URL the private key?

Answer (score 3):

No, Instawallet is a hosted (shared) EWallet.

They do not provide to you the private key for the deposit addresses associated with your Instawallet.

When you request a withdrawal, Instawallet processes that request and makes the transaction.  There is no way for you to create a withdrawal transaction yourself for any funds in an Instawallet.

Comment: Thank you for the comment..Doesn't the URL they provided have the private key on the end of it? All my families ones do? I thought this was the private key as they said you should not lose it otherwise you cant access your coins?

Comment: The URL may be some hash or calculation of the private address, but even if so, it would be essentially impossible to reverse it into revealing the true private key.

Comment: ok..dam..I was thinking those No's/letters were the key.